# How to make a status bar icon with retina support in Python?

Tags: python, statusbar, menubar, pyobjc, retina

I make an icon using these codes:

```
self.statusbar = NSStatusBar.systemStatusBar()
self.statusitem = self.statusbar.statusItemWithLength_(NSVariableStatusItemLength)
self.image = NSImage.alloc().initWithData_(IMAGE_DATA)
self.statusitem.setImage_(self.image)
```

But it is very ugly on Macbook Pro with Retina Display.

How can I make the status bar icon support retina display in Python?

Answer (score 0):

The same as with Objecive-C: make sure the image object contains a retina representation of the image. The easiest way to do this is use named images (base.png and base@2x.png in the resources folder, then use a named NSImage)